# Python Twitter API How to search for tweets containing an exact phrase?

Tags: python, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

```
query = twitter.search.tweets(q = "Andorra Park Hotel")
```

So the problem I'm having is that this returns tweets containing these 3 words but not the phrase itself. So I'm getting tweets that have "Andorra" in it and "Park" in it and "Hotel" somewhere else. What I want is to get tweets containing this phrase or this exact String so the words follow each other consecutively. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

To have a exact phrase match you need to have your string between " characters. 
so your query ends up looking like this :

```
"\"Andorra Park Hotel\""
```